# Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_turkish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '=' and why?

Tags: mariadb, collation

Hello I got error in mariadb. In my command  two columns have different collate. one is utf8_unicode_ci (a) other is utf8_turkish_ci (b). Why I got error when I compare these columns ( where a = b )  both of them utf8.
Error:
    Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_turkish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Answer (score 3):

It would be useful if you can provide your tables definition. However, your error suggests that your are trying to check equality between two columns having different collation.

One solution is to change collation of one of the columns to match the other collation. Check [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/setting-character-sets-and-collations/) - Column Level.

Other solution is to use [COLLATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collate.html) clause (I do not know if this works in mariadb, but it should be there).

Personally, I prefer to avoid COLLATE and harmonize string columns as collation mismatch tend to force lots of COLLATEs (maintenance problems).

Comment: I would just add that the reason for the error is that the results of `=` might be different depending on which collation is used, and the server has no way to decide which one is the *right* one, so you have to tell it.